# How to get the two "Statuette" quests done?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I've already played *The Witcher 3* three times, but I never could never do any of the two *statuette* quests: "The Nobleman Statuette" and "The Soldier Statuette" quests. Actually, I got the first one done, once but totally at random and I don't know how I did.

I must be doing something wrong in my quests order.

So in order for me to get both of those quests done, what quest line should I follow?

In my current playthrough, I'm currently at the second Novigrad quest, "Novigrad Deaming", I have the nobleman statuette, I go to Triss in her appartment, and she tells me to "decompress" it, but the only dialog option after that is "bye". I'm playing on PS4, if that has any kind of influence.

Side note, yes I know those quests are bugged if not done at the right moment, that's the goal of my question: at what moment do I need to do them to not get the bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing it, here's why I got:

I had to wait until immediately after the quest "A Poet Under Pressure" (last quest of the Novigrad quest line) before being able to progress in "The Nobleman Statuette".

After that I could progress in "The Soldier Statuette" after finishing "A Dangerous Game", in which you usually get the statuette itself. But I still had to wait for the "A Dangerous Game" quest to be finished before completing "The Soldier Statuette" quest.

Important information: Triss' path was NOT started.

Answer (score 2):

Triss can help you with the statuette quests. It depends when you find them, but before the battle of Kaer Morhen you can talk with Triss and she will help.

To update - there is a time after battle of Kaer Morhen, when she is freely available to just talk and not in the middle of any quest. Also, you can talk with her after the main quest line ending, then she will help to decompress the statues.

Comment: Of course it has to happen before the Battle for Kaer Mohen. It has to happen before the quest "Now or Never", which occurs before the battle. My question is exactly when. Your answer is too vague, unfortunately.

Comment: @ogregoire No, it can be after the Battle, Triss is available to talk to later on.

Comment: That's fine. I did complete those quests in my play. I even skipped one since I went too far in the main quest line.

Comment: Sorry, I won't accept this answer because I found exactly what needed to be done to get it. And your answers make those quests rather late in the game while it can be done before starting the 3rd part of act 1. See my answer for details. You get my +1 though because you've probably helped people who got those late in the game.

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve the same things in the game. No need to be sorry, this is not about points, but about helping.